# dynamic reference to javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reference

I have a master page with a reference to javascript file that is js folder.
Both File and masterpage are in the root directory.

Many of my forms are in different folders Like

```
  Root>first>abc.aspx
  Root>second>def.aspx
  Root>second>anotherFolder>def.aspx
```

I kept the reference like this

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Check.js"></script>
```

I also tried `src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/Check.js") %>"` and `src="~/js/Check.js"`. While using `Page.ResolveUrl` and `Server.ResolveUrl` page shows error.

What i need to do so that any form in any directory get the reference of the file.
I dont want to do `../` and `../../` in every form.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Check.js"></script>
```

you can use "/" --> web site root

Comment: Actual path is http://localhost:1500/AppName/js/Check.js and with "/" it references http://localhost:1500/js/Check.js. The error still holds.

Comment: are you using virtual directory?

Comment: Yes i m using virtual directory

Comment: also script reference is in my head tag

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your Visual Studio's internal server for debugging then firstly remove the virtual folder it insists on using.

Do this by selecting the root of your site in VS Solution explorer, then right-click and choose "Properties Window" - in the properties change "Virtual Path" from your "AppName" to `/`

This virtual path plays havoc with all sorts of paths..I find that if i don't make this change in VS then when I DO get all my paths working they won't work when I put the site on a live server that isn't using a virtual site.

Then set your JS reference to `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Check.js"></script>` - using the root `/` in your src.

**UPDATE**

If you really want to keep the virtual folder then you can try this - using `ResolveClientUrl()`:

First, add `Runat="Server"` to your `<head>`

```
<head runat="server" id="myhead">

<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/check.js") %>' />
```

Comment: good point. Thanks. is there another way without removing virtual folder i.e. by code

Comment: If you're not going to be putting it in a virtual directory on the server then i would strongly advise not trying to hack it. it gets VERY messy..

Comment: i will put this in iis virtual directory and then convert it to application.

Comment: Error as i described in question. "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."

Comment: also script reference is in my head tag

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29998/discussion-between-syed-mohsin-and-darren)

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to chat. make the changes i updated with and it should work. If not, then open another question as there will be something else causing the issue